# Найти слово в тексте по его части и вывести

Tags: python, поиск

Есть текст после распознания
Пример:
text = 'Я пришел в дом 3700121'
word = '3700'
Мне нужно по части слова (word) найти номер дома в тексте и вывести полный номер (3700121).

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = text.split()
for i in text:
    if word in i:
        print(i)
```